# Audio cuts in and out when using Spotify Linux Preview

Tags: sound

I'm not sure how many people on this forum use [Spotify](http://www.spotify.com), but here goes.

I have [Spotify Linux Preview](http://www.spotify.com/int/download/previews/) installed on Ubuntu 10.10 and so far it has worked perfectly for me. In the past few days however, the audio keeps cutting in an out intermittently. I'm not sure whether this is an audio issue, or a streaming issue, or a caching issue. Is anyone else facing the same problem - or know how to narrow down what could be the cause?

FYI, I have also [raised this issue on the official Spotify support forum](http://getsatisfaction.com/spotify/topics/audio_problem_in_spotify_linux_preview). I know there's [a similar problem for Spotify being run on WINE](http://www.spotify.com/int/help/faq/wine/#playback-stutter) that can be solved by changing to OSS from PulseAudio in WINE, but that doesn't seem to be issue here with the native Linux client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Spotify reps on their GetSatisfaction forum, [this issue has been resolved in the 0.5.1.151 release of Spotify Preview for Linux](http://getsatisfaction.com/spotify/topics/audio_problem_in_spotify_linux_preview#reply_5748282).